# Rotate an ionicon on the page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionicons

I want to display directions with an arrow and was thinking to use the standard ionic arrow for the direction.
Can I rotate the up arrow into any direction somehow?

```
ion-arrow-up-a
```

Here is an attempt from the comments below

```
<i class="icon ion-arrow-up-a" rotate degrees="90"></i>


angular.module('app.customDirectives', []).directive('rotate', function() {
      return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // watch the degrees attribute, and update the UI when it changes
                scope.$watch(attrs.degrees, function(rotateDegrees) {
//                  console.log(rotateDegrees);
                    //transform the css to rotate based on the new rotateDegrees
                    element.css({
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)',
                        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)',
                        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)'
                    });
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [tag:jquery-rotate] plugin?

Comment: I am in the ionic sphere here, so no jquery ( I guess, as I understand jQ is not fully supported / compatible there...)

Answer (score 14):

Similar to above, this is how I did it...

HTML:

```
<i class="ion-arrow-up-c rotate-90">
```

CSS:

```
.rotate-90 {
  display: inline-block; 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For Ionic icons v1, v2 specifically, the rotate property works only with the display property set to "inline" or "inline-block", it might work with other variations of inline as well.

Then you can rotate them normally using CSS

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is other variants of arrow:

```
ion-arrow-up-a
ion-arrow-right-a
ion-arrow-down-a
ion-arrow-left-a
```

Or... As I know, ionic framework is HTML5 based, so you can use CSS styles.

```
.style {
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

If you want dynamic rotation, you have to check [this url](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/compass-rotation-with-ionic/14517).

Comment: Great link! I understand the directive, but it does not rotate my ion-arrow .... I need it to display degrees like in a compass.

Comment: @ElDude Show your code and I will try to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: See code above, basically same from the link you provided.

Comment: @ElDude You can find answer to your question in the same place, where u took this code (link above). You have to create `$scope` var and pass it to `degrees`, not just value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But why should it not take hardcoded values?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the `<i>` element has to own `display: inline-block` css style to rotate successfully:

controller code:

```
$scope.angle = 90
```

HTML:

```
<i class="ion-arrow-up-c" style="display: inline-block; transform: rotate({{angle}}deg);"></i>
```